# wallpaper app source probem in showing data

Tags: android

When I am trying to upload my app in Google Play I am getting following error.

```
Upload failed

You uploaded a debuggable APK. For security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play. Learn more about debuggable APKs.
```

Comment: Can you share some code from build gradle of the app

Comment: Please provide more information on how you have created the signed apk.

Comment: this is my build.gradle justpaste.it/21wbn

Answer (score 3):

Remove this line from build.gradle

```
        debuggable true
```

Comment: but i don't  have this cod